# How to interpret c++ opencv Assertion error messages due to an error in cvtColor function?

Tags: c++, opencv, assertion

Following is an Assertion Error report (displayed on console) when calling cvtColor() function in opencv giving the argument CV_GRAY2BGR  on a Mat object which is already a BGR image. I want to know how to interpret this error message by a person who yet doesn't know what the error here. (Hope some erudites won't vote to close this question as off topic, as I know there is a big value in learning to read Assertion or any other error messages for newbees for c++. ) And as I guess this might be most probably a opencv issue on reading assertion errors.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 ||
 dcn == 4)) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-shared\open
cv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3791
```

I know 2 conditions are tested here,

1. (scn == 1)
2. (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4)

and one of them should have failed which has caused the Assertion error. How to distinct and clarify the failed condition? May be I might have to seek into the cvtColor function source code and that would be no problem. (actually I did it but I couldn't find variables with names scn or dcn there in that improc.cpp class there)

Comment: If you passed a bgr Mat, I.e. 3 channel, the first assertion failed, since source channel (scn) is not 1. Dcn is destination channel. You should check color.cpp (as reported in the error) and not improc.cpp. Last, but not least, use the debugger...

Comment: means: SourceChannelNumber must be 1 (grayscale) and DestinationChannelNumber must be 3 or 4 (color image)

Comment: @Miki and Micka, both of u re amazing...! ;-) Thanks for the support. Pls add these comments as a answer and I would mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Anyway there is a new problem for me now. I checked the color.cpp. Yes , those variables were in that class. But where are their meaning (as scn=source channel number and dcn =destination channel number) is defined..? I mean where are the comments clarifying the long phrases of those abbreviated variable names. mmm... OR do we have to use general sense or guesses to decide the meanings...

Comment: Usually there are no comments. You deduce what they mean looking at the arguments of the function, or how the variable is initialized. A little of experience and you'll become familiar with such names and assertions meaning. As I said earlier, stepping in with a debugger is very useful to follow function calls and ultimately find out the error

Comment: Thanks @Miki. I use Visual Studio 2013 in built debugger. Are there any other better debuggers which c++ experts use?

Comment: I use mostly VS too, and personally I find it excellent (just a personal opinion). With other IDE you may use gdb and valgrind ( but I'm not quite affordable here)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This snippet

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Just a small green BGR image
    Mat3b img(10,10,Vec3b(0,255,0));

    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, CV_GRAY2BGR); // WARNING: this won't work (on purpose)

    return 0;
}
```

will produce your exact error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4)) in cv::cvtCo
>   lor, file C:\builds\2_4_PackSlave-win32-vc12-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\c
>   olor.cpp, line 3789

---

This code is obviuosly wrong, because you're trying to convert an BGR image from GRAY.

OpenCV is telling you:

> Since you're using the code `CV_GRAY2BGR`, I'm expecting to convert from GRAY (1 channel) source image to a BGR (3 channel) destination image. (I'll allow also BGRA (4 channels) as destination image, even if `CV_GRAY2BGRA` would be more appropriate in this case.)

In the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) OpenCV is telling you:

- *src*: input image: 8-bit unsigned, 16-bit unsigned ( CV_16UC... ), or single-precision floating-point.
- *dst*: output image of the same size **and depth** as src.
- *code*: color space conversion code (see the description below).
- *dstCn*: **number of channels in the destination image**; if the parameter is 0, the number of the channels is derived automatically from src and code .

In C++, OpenCV say this as

```
CV_Assert( scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4));
```

where `scn` stands for "Source Channels Number", and `dcn` stands for "Destination Channels Number".

Now the last point, where do `scn` and `dcn` comes from? If you use a debugger and follow the execution path, you'll see in function `void cv::cvtColor( InputArray _src, OutputArray _dst, int code, int dcn )` in `color.cpp` that (comments added by me):

```
void cv::cvtColor( InputArray _src /* source image*/, 
                   OutputArray _dst /* destination image*/,  
                   int code, /* here is CV_GRAY2BGR*/ 
                   int dcn /* defaults to -1*/ ) 
{
    Mat src = _src.getMat(), dst;
    ...
    int scn = src.channels(); // scn is the number of channels of the source image 
    ...
    switch( code ) {
        ...
        case CV_GRAY2BGR: case CV_GRAY2BGRA:
            if( dcn <= 0 ) dcn = (code==CV_GRAY2BGRA) ? 4 : 3; 
            // destination channels are set to 3 because of the code CV_GRAY2BGR

            // Check that the input arguments are correct
            CV_Assert( scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long definition. This answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> calling cvtColor() function in opencv giving the argument CV_GRAY2BGR on a Mat object which is already a BGR image

You have already answered your own question here.  The assertion will have originally have been something like:

`CV_Assert( scn == 1 && (dcn == 3 || dcn == 4));`

Since you're using a BGR Mat, `scn` -  which is the number of channels in the source Mat - will be `3` causing the whole expression to evaluate to `false`, and the assertion to fail.

The operation you are performing makes no sense.  Omit it, and your code will probably work.

Comment: The answer I expected is actually an interpretation of the error report but not what the error is. Anyway thanks. Micka and Miki have given the answers as I expected.

Comment: Anyway there is a new problem for me now. I checked the color.cpp. Yes , those variables were in that class. But where are their meaning (as scn=source channel number and dcn =destination channel number) is defined..? I mean where are the comments clarifying the long phrases of those abbreviated variable names.

Comment: @SamithaChathuranga: Read my answer more carefully ;) OpenCV doesn't really lend itself to being treated as a black-box library and can be quite developer-hostile at times.  There's nothing for it but to delve into the (vast amounts of) source code.

Comment: ok. Some other problem here. Guess I am doing all correctly calling cvtColor(sourceMat,sourceMat,CV_BGR2GRAY); I give the same source image as both the input and output Mat. So dcn is not 3 or 4 either. (it is still 1 as it is the grayscale image still). But no assertion would show up. So what is the real scenario there.?

Comment: Are you sure that `cvtColor()` can perform this conversion in-place?  I suspect it can't - so you'll need to construct a Mat to use as the second parameter.

Comment: So, the documentation for `cvtColor()` which states: "dst – output image of the same size and depth as src." - this is not quite saying that they have to have the same number of channels.  The example they give does show an in-place conversion, but this is one with the same number of input and output channel count.

Comment: Yes, cvtColor() can perform that conversion. (directly converting the source RGB image to grayscale). I have done it many times.