# How to understand this exception raised in an OpenCV program

Tags: opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, android

[image]

I have got the following exception in my OpenCV program. I had the following image in my computer and I moved it to my mobile phone and read it by `Mat imageRead = Highgui.imread("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/2im00.png");`

[image]

Then I tried to convert its color space to HSV using the following statement, and got the exception on this statement.

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(imageRead, hsvImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
```

But the exception does not seem to tell me anything more than that it is in the function `cvtColor`, or I can't read the encoded information there.

So the question is that how do I find out why I am getting this exception?

Is there any coded information there, like some codes (like scn==3 or scn==4 or error:-215 or depth etc etc), which I can browse somewhere to find out why I am getting the exception?

Comment: Have a look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32035702/5008845). OpenCV it's saying you that your source image channels `scn`should be 3 or 4, while it's depth should be unsigned char (CV_8U) or float (CV_32F)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably, Assertion failure occurs because you are passing an empty image to the cvtColor function. 
Or
The Mat image you are passing is not an CV_8U or CV_32F format.

I agree with Miki's comment for more details follow this link [How to interpret c++ opencv Assertion error messages due to an error in cvtColor function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027849/how-to-interpret-c-opencv-assertion-error-messages-due-to-an-error-in-cvtcolor/32035702#32035702)

Comment: You should also add the link from Miki's comment, because that will make your answer more useful for future visitors. (Don't forget to give due credit to them).