# Tried converting an image from RGB to GRAYSCALE using opencv on python, didn't got the results?

Tags: opencv3.0

error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

error: /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:10638: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to interpret c++ opencv Assertion error messages due to an error in cvtColor function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32027849/how-to-interpret-c-opencv-assertion-error-messages-due-to-an-error-in-cvtcolor)

Comment: Your `image` is not a 3 or 4 channel image. print its `shape`

Comment: can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: a little effort plase...  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19098258/5008845

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that the image you are trying to read is not in the path you provided. OpenCV doesn't throw an error in this case but just returns a none type.

Now, when you try to convert the none type to a gray image, you get the above error.

[Check out the image i have posted. In this code, 'a.jpg' does not exist in the default path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMpX0.jpg)